# Homebrew giving error that SDK not found (MacOS 11/10.16)

Tags: macos, homebrew, macos-big-sur

I trying to install a formula with Brew. But I always get a an Error:

```
Error: Could not find an SDK that supports macOS 11.0.
You may have have an outdated or incompatible CLT.
Homebrew found the following SDKs in the CLT install:
  10.14
  10.15

Please update CLT or uninstall it if no updates are available.
```

I have updated to Xcode 12 Beta as well and set my CLT path to that too but I still get this error. Can anybody please help me fix this?

Comment: go to this
https://developer.apple.com/download/more/
and download and install the tools it works for me the error disappeared

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You should install Command Line Tools for Xcode 12 beta 3 [here](https://developer.apple.com/download/more/)

Comment: Did not work for me after installing both Xcode 12 GM and the CLTs manually.

Comment: ```bash

❯ pkgutil --pkg-info=com.apple.pkg.CLTools_Executables

package-id: com.apple.pkg.CLTools_Executables
version: 12.0.0.0.1.1599194153
volume: /
location: /
install-time: 1600280469
groups: com.apple.FindSystemFiles.pkg-group
```

Comment: This worked for me. I'm quite sure I'd installed these previously, but had recently updated my Mac OSX version to BigSur, so I guess that wiped it. I was actually getting the error about MacOSX 11.1. Afterwards I was able to proceed with `brew reinstall gcc`.

Comment: I found that I was getting the message `command line tools cannot be installed on this disk. the version of macos is too new`. This was addressed by installing the version of command line tools that corresponded to the version of XCode I had installed.