# Unable to install nvm on Big Sur, CLT not found

Tags: nvm, macos-big-sur

I am setting up a new computer with the Big Sur beta and I am unable to get CLT (command line tools) to install properly or be registered. I have installed Homebrew but when I try to install nvm (brew install nvm) I get an error:

```
Error: Your CLT does not support macOS 11.0.
It is either outdated or was modified.
Please update your CLT or delete it if no updates are available.
```

I've followed [Homebrew giving error that SDK not found (MacOS 11/10.16)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63096580/homebrew-giving-error-that-sdk-not-found-macos-11-10-16) with no luck. I've installed CLT via the apple developer download (for Xcode 12) without luck. I've installed Xcode 12 directly and still no luck.

When I query CLT via `xcodeselect -v` it returns: xcode-select version 2383

Does anyone have any ideas what is going on?

Answer (score 0):

`xcode-select --install` didn't work for me and had to download the binary to install it. I was able to install homebrew, however, but `brew doctor` gives me this message. I imagine it'll be sorted out in the near future.

Comment: You forgot to add the message you get from brew. @chirul0

Comment: Cause it's essentially the same: ```Warning: Your CLT does not support macOS 11.0.
It is either outdated or was modified.
Please update your CLT or delete it if no updates are available.```

Comment: Ah ok, you meant "same message" instead of "this message" :)